# If $A$ has the subset topology in $X$ and $D \subset A$, does $Int_{A}D \subset A \cap Int_{X}D$?

Tags: general-topology

This exercise is from the section on the subspace topology in Introduction to Topology, Pure and Applied by Adams and Franzosa.

To make the subspace topology, we take a topological space $X$ with $A\subset X$ and define $T_Y = \{A\cap U | U \text{ is open in } X\}$. Now suppose $D \subset A$. By $Int_{X}D$ and $Int_{A}D$ we mean the interior of $D$ in $X$ and the interior of $D$ in the subspace topology $A$ inherits from $X$. Now for the problem:

Show $Int_{A}D \subset A \cap Int_{X}D$.

My issue is that I think I have a counter example. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, $A = [0,2]$, $D=(1,2]$. We have $Int_{A}D = (1,2]$ since $(1,2] = A \cap (1,3)$. In other words, $D$ is actually open in the subspace topology because I can find an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and intersect it with $A$ to get $D$. Then we look at $A \cap Int_{X}D = A \cap (1,2) = (1,2)$, so $2$ is missing from the right side of the containment above. Is this a working counterexample?

Intuitively, open sets in $A$ may not be open in $X$. I've abused that to squeeze an extra point into $Int_{A}D$ that would prevent $D$ from being open in $X$.

I can prove the reverse containment. Let $x \in   Int_X D$. Since $Int_X D$ is open, we have an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contained in $Int_X D$. Since $U \subset D \subset A$, we have that $U$ is open in $A$ and $U \subset Int_A D$, so $x \in Int_A D$. Does this mean there's just a typo?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the official site, but [the book's errata hosted here](http://euclid.nmu.edu/%7Ejoshthom/Teaching/MA366/CorrectionsTop.pdf) mentions this:

> Page 81, Exercises 3.11(a). This exercise is incorrect. Replace it with:
>
> (a) Explore the relationship between $Int_AD$ and $A \cap Int_XD.$ For each containment $\subset$ and $\supset$, either prove that it holds or find a counterexample.

As for your questions, your counterexample and your proof of the reversed containment both work.